# Encoding a column in Pandas based on occurance of value 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want to make another column with values like this,

`[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`

The idea is to start with value `1` and increment the value when I get a `1` and only if the last value was `0`. In other words, if I have a `0` then increment the value in the next step.

I used an apply to do this like shown below,

```
k = 1

def fn(row):

    global k
    a, b = row['A'], row['x']

    if a == 1 and b == 1:
        pass
    elif a == 1 and b == 0:
        pass
    elif a == 0 and b == 1:
        k += 1
        return (k - 1)
    else:
        k += 1
        return (k - 1)

    return k

df['x'] = df['A'].shift(-1)
df['k'] = df.apply(lambda row : fn(row), axis=1)
```

Which is really inefficient. I can't figure out a faster method for this.

How to implement this in Pandas efficiently.?

Comment: If the input is something like `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` I want it to be `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to count the occurrence of `0` but shifted:

```
df['A'].eq(0).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)+1
```

Or:

```
df['A'].shift().eq(0).cumsum()+1
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the speed part

```
s=df.index[df.A.eq(0)]
pd.Series(np.arange(len(s))+1,index=s).reindex(df.index,method='bfill')
Out[41]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
dtype: int32
```